# iOS8 Retina @2x images not scaling like iOS7?

Tags: swift, ios8, sprite-kit

Has the way that Xcode 6.1 (iOS 8.1) changed the way that images are handled. In my previous Sprite Kit game (Xcode 5, iOS 7) I used the following full screen image as a  background:

```
MainBackground_IP5@2x.png // RESOLUTION: 640 x 1136, it fills screen.
```

Now in Xcode 6.1 I am testing the following code (See below), the image I am using is:

```
MainBackground_IP6@2x.png // RESOLUTION: 750 x 1334
```

CODE:

```
func setupBackdrop() {
    println(__FUNCTION__)
    let backdropSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "MainBackground_IP6")
    backdropSprite.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
    backdropSprite.position = CGPointZero
    self.addChild(backdropSprite)
}
```

However when I run the application both on the simulator and device I get the following.

[image]

NOTE: If I remove the @2x it fits fine, but I can,t understand whats changed, I have not seen this mentioned in any Sprite Kit notes? I even loaded my old iPhone 5 game project and all the @2x backgrounds fit perfectly in that, it must just be iOS 8.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images should use @2x but the problem was that in the GameScene.sks I had entered the screen resolution in pixels not points (should have been 375 x 667) Also there seems to be a problem with the GameScene.sks on the template, if you add items programatically as I did they quite often don't display. The solution to this seems to be that you have to add at least one node to the GameScene.sks (I just added an empty SKNode)